# How to use Azure API for FHIR Server without any authorization token

Tags: azure, hl7-fhir, fhir-server-for-azure

I have created a resource for **Azure API for FHIR Server**. I am able to get see the metadata information using the URL like https://fhir-server-url/metadata. As mentioned in the documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/healthcare-apis/access-fhir-postman-tutorial to access other URLs like https://fhir-server-url/Patient, we need to get the Authorization token first. To get the authorization token we need ClientID which we can get by creating an application in Azure Active Directory. But I don't have access to it.

Is there any way I could access this URL without requiring the authorization token? By making some setup in Azure Portal.

Comment: You have to create app registration in AAD, there is no other way to get client Id & client secret to retrieve the authorization token.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using the first party audience (e.g. https://azurehealthcareapis), which is the default when deploying the Azure API for FHIR, you can actually use a first party client application such as the Azure CLI to get a token. Check https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/healthcare-apis/get-healthcare-apis-access-token-cli for details.

First log in with the Azure CLI (https://learn.microsoft.com/cli/azure/?view=azure-cli-latest) :

```
az login
```

Get a token and store it

```
token=$(az account get-access-token --resource=https://azurehealthcareapis.com | jq -r .accessToken)
```

Use the token:

```
curl -X GET --header "Authorization: Bearer $token" https://<FHIR ACCOUNT NAME>.azurehealthcareapis.com/Patient
```

Comment: Thanks! Good to know that such an option also exist.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like from the FHIR Server Doc you can turn this on or off based on the **FhirServer:Security:Enabled** config setting see https://github.com/microsoft/fhir-server/blob/master/docs/Authentication.md

```
"FhirServer" : {
"Security": {
    "Enabled":  true,
    "Authentication": {
        "Audience": "fhir-api",
        "Authority": "https://localhost:44348"
    }
}}
```

Comment: This only applies to the OSS FHIR server. The managed Azure API for FHIR always has security turned on.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to get your app registration in Azure Active Directory(AAD).

You would need two app registrations in AAD to get client Id & client secret for authorization token retrieval.

Comment: there are first party clients that can be used. See below.